# Code analysis using fxCop for C#..NET projects to display its results in Sonar

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, static-analysis, fxcop, sonarqube

I am in need of running static code analysis using fxCop for C#..NET projects and display its results in Sonar? I am new to Sonar. Can I run FxCop from Sonar on .NET code. How would I do this and get the results displayed in sonar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sonar to display results genrated by FxCop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675892/sonar-to-display-results-genrated-by-fxcop)

Comment: Asking the same question over and over wastes people's time

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice !

Answer (score 1):

You can find anything to get started here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C-Sharp+Plugins+Ecosystem

See the C# example application that we use to test the Sonar C# Plugin here: http://svn.codehaus.org/sonar-plugins/trunk/dotnet/tools/dotnet-tools-commons/src/test/resources/solution/Example/

Answer (score 0):

Sonar is an open source software quality platform. Sonar uses various static code analysis tools such as Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs , FxCop , Gendarme and many more to extract software metrics, which then can be used to improve software quality.
Sonar provides some useful metrics for pointing out hotspots in your code that may be making it more difficult to maintain and extend your functionality. SONAR provides a web interface using which we can drill-down on any of the metrics to the module, class, and method level, including full source code.

Coming to your question, ***YES*** , you can run FxCop using Sonar Client.
The complete procedure to run sonar analysis is as follows:

- Set Up and configuration of Sonar Server
- Set up and configuration of Sonar Client
- Install Sonar Plugins for C# environment (C# ecosystem)
- running Sonar Analysis using Sonar client
- Analyzing Sonar Analysis over Sonar Server web interface.

If your sonar analysis is complete then all the results will get published over the Sonar web server portal , you configured.
For detailed procedure for setup,configuring and running sonar analysis over C# project [visit here.](http://counsellingbyabhi.blogspot.in/2013/06/setting-up-sonar-server-and-client-on.html)

For C# ecosystem in SONAR [click here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C#+Ecosystem).