# Sonar to display results generated by FxCop

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, static-analysis, fxcop, sonarqube

How can I use Sonar to display results of the output produced by FxCop. I used FxCop to run static code analysis on .NET Project and FxCop generate the result report in an XML format. Can I use Sonar to take this XML file an input and display the output with it? How can this be done? I am looking for an open source dash board tool to present the output the result produced by FxCop to the end user.

Answer (score 2):

Sonar has a C# plug-in, documented here:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C-Sharp+Plugins+Ecosystem

A sample .NET project is hosted on Sonarsource's demo platform:

http://nemo.sonarsource.org/dashboard/index/org.mybatis:mybatisdotnet

Comment: Thanks Mark for you reply. From the documentation looks like in order to use sonar I would have to user Maven to build and to run static code analysis through FxCop from Maven. Can I user MsBuild as my build agent and have FxCop as one of the build step with in MsBuild then publish/view that analysis report in Sonar ? I am using TeamCity as my CI envrioment and MSBuild to perform the Build , Static Code Analysis and execute Unit Test (MSTest). I would like to view use Sonar to view the results produced (XML,trx) by FxCop and MSTest.

Comment: The new c# plug-in is a complete re-write of the older .NET plug-in. You don't require Maven anymore, Sonar analysis is performed by the new Java runner. Another key difference is that the new plugin no longer attempts to build your code, just performs source code analysis. Finally this is all cutting edge stuff, but .NET support in Sonar is getting better with every release.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am asuming Java runner is another Static Code analaysis too like FxCop. Can I user it run analysis on C# code ? I have never used Java runner, wher can I find an example on how to user Java runner to run static code on c# code and publish the results with Sonar?

Comment: No.... Java runner is the new way to launch Sonar analysis. Replaces the need to launch everything from Maven. I suggest reading the documentation.